# Georeferencer will not run

Tags: qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I am new to QGIS and trying to understand it to draw historical maps. I run Windows 10 and QGIS 3.10 5. Previously I have used the georeferencer to load map Jpegs but trying to load one yesterday the Georeferencer just didn't open.
I tried it several times, closed the program and windows down and restarted several times. On one occasion and the plug in disappeared from the plugin drop down.I installed the more recent release but the same issue it wont run. I have gone back to 3.10.5 the plugin is there but will not run.

Answer (score 2):

That's an old known issue ([Georeferencer plugin will not load in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83334)), that happens when you switch from 2 monitor display to a single one and leaves the georeferencer window on the second monitor window.
You can solve this problem in the advanced option dialog, if you reset *pos* to (0,0):

[image]

If the georeferencer window was docked the last time, may be it helps to remove everything except *Minimize* from *Plugin-GeoReferencer>Config*:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to this "old known issue", please?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83334/georeferencer-plugin-will-not-load-in-qgis - in QGIS for Windows the *Advanced Settings Editor* enables us to edit the Windows Registry without regedit.exe, which is disabled in most cases.

Comment: I am not using two monitors but I will look and see if it helps

Comment: I have tried the suggestion. Pos was set to -187,88. I reset to 0,0 . Closed QGIS and restarted, still nor working. Went back into options and pos now reads "invalid" I now cannot editit pos, it will not highlight

Comment: Ok, there are still some options left ... read this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83334/georeferencer-plugin-will-not-load-in-qgis - Maybe you have to edit *QGIS.ini* or your georeferencer is docked and you have to enable the dock-window.

Comment: Try to delete all entries except *Minimize* in *Plugin-GeoReferencer>Config* as I show in my updated answer.